# Are $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{18}$ integers where $a_0 = 1, a_{n+1}=\frac{1 + a_0^k + \cdots + a_n^k}{n + 1}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $k\ge 2$ be an integer. Define the sequence $a_n$ by the following.

> $$a_0 = 1,$$
>
> $$a_{n+1}=\frac{1 + a_0^k + \cdots + a_n^k}{n + 1}$$

You notice the least $n$ for which $a_n$ is nonintegral are probably greater than or equal to 19.

（https://oeis.org/A108394）

Prove or disprove

$a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{18}$ are integers for any $k \ge 2$.

Comment: Maybe note that $a_n^k=1$ for every $n$? Because you wrongly copied the recursion...

Comment: For $k=2$ it's called [Göbel's Sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoebelsSequence.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matsuhira, Matsusaka, & Tsuchida prove that least $n$ for which $a_n$ is nonintegral are greater than or equal to 19. [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.09741)